# How to troubleshoot the error "Error Code: 10609 - Invalid transactionID.: (Transaction id is invalid.)" when calling the "DoAuthorization"" method?

Tags: paypal

First, I'm calling DoDirectPayment and DoVoid method to reference the credit card in paypal. These are working correctly and Paypal return the TransactionID for these transaction. Then I use this TRANSACTIONID when calling DoAuthorization method (paymentaction is 'Authorization') but the given code always returns the error Transaction id is invalid.

Thanks for help!

Comment: It looks as if you are attempting to run a reference transaction. If you "void" the parent transaction the transaction ID will indeed be invalid because you voided it.

Answer (score 2):

It looks as if you are attempting to run a reference transaction. If you "void" the parent transaction the transaction ID will indeed be invalid because you voided it. Instead, try running an authorization in the amount of $0 and reference THAT transaction ID for future transactions.

Also, Reference transactions is a feature that needs to be enabled on the PayPal account. I hope this helps.